# Globally generated sheaf arising from orthogonal Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, grassmannians, projective-varieties

We will use the Grothendieck's notation, according to the book of Hartshorne.

Let us consider a finite dimension $\mathbb C$-vector space $V$, with a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form $q:V \times V \to \mathbb C$. Then one can define the orthogonal Grassmannians as
$$
OG(k,V)=\{\mathbb P W \subset \mathbb PV: \dim W=k \text{ and }W \text{ is }q-\text{isotropic}\} \subset G(k,V)
$$
which is naturally contained in the standard Grassmannian $G(k,V)$. If $\mathcal E$ is a vector bundle on $G(k,V)$, we will denote again by $\mathcal E$ its pullback via the inclusion $OG(k,V) \hookrightarrow G(k,V)$. Following Munoz, Occhetta and Sola Conde ([see here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10908)), one can define a vector bundle $\mathcal K$ that fits in the short exact sequence of vector bundles over $OG(k,V)$
$$
0 \to \mathcal K \to \mathcal S \to \mathcal Q \to 0
$$
where $\mathcal Q, \mathcal S$ are the universal bundles fitting the sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal S^\vee \to V \otimes \mathcal O \to \mathcal Q \to 0.
$$

The theory tells us that both $\mathcal Q, \mathcal S$ are globally generated, so it will be $\mathcal K$ too? If not, how can one find $m$ such that $\mathcal K(m)$ is globally generated?

Comment: Which is the question you are interested in: the one in the title (the answer is negative) or the one at the end of your text? Anyway, this is much more appropriate on SE. And you should be more accurate in asking if you want others to answer.